# Generic points as coefficients of polynomial kernels?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I am reading the paper [Dual-to-Kernel Learning with Ideals](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0099.pdf). Here is part of it:

[image]

The definition/motivation of genericity in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_point) are

> A generic point of the topological space $X$ is a point $P$ whose
>   closure is all of $X$, that is, a point that is dense in $X$.  The
>   terminology arises from the case of the Zariski topology of algebraic
>   varieties. For example having a generic point is a criterion to be an
>   irreducible set.

I cannot see why this gives the linear independence in Theorem 1 immediately. Any hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the meaning of "generic" you're looking for, although there's a historical relationship. If you try to think of your $y_i$ as generic points, or as constituting a generic point, you run into immediate problems since $\mathbb{K}^n$ will not have a generic point under any common topology (points are closed in all important examples.)

The "generic" here means "in general position," i.e. the $y_1...y_m$ aren't supposed to lie on the zero set of any polynomial of degree less than $m-1$. (It's best to think of this for $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$ and $n=1$.) The claim then is just that being linearly dependent under $k_*$ would give such a polynomial relation.